# How would a courtier of the Ancien Régime have translated the phrase "Her Illustrious Highness"?

Tags: traduction

I'm trying to find the best translation for the Russian term **Сиятельство**. (I can't speak Russian either! So don't expect too much from me in that regard.) This is a form of address, often translated into English as **Illustrious Highness**. In the old Russian Empire, it was the default form of address for **princes and princesses** not part of the imperial family. (With the tsar's blessing, some princely families used the higher style of Serene Highness, but let's not get into all that!)

The **literal translation** of Her Illustrious Highness would, I think, be ***Son altesse illustre***. However, I know from the Monégasque princely family that their style - the official English form of which is His/Her Serene Highness - is *Son altesse sérénissime*, and not *Son altesse sereine*. Might ***Son altesse illustrissime*** then be a more **elegant** translation? Or is that just nonsense?

Comment: Thanks to your question, I learned a new false friend: "courtier" that translates to *courtisan* in French while *courtier* means "broker", +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have too much knowledge of historical context around it, but having grown up for a large part of my life in a French environment (France !) I’m almost positive the word *majesté* (literally « majesty ») is the best word to associate with « *illustre* », in terms of frequency of use.

Though the Monégasque princely family seems to be using a similar phrase, your idea of using *son altesse illustrissime* sounds mostly like a humorous exaggeration to a mere mortal, while *son altesse illustre* could probably work if you instead said « *illustre altesse* » (French can also have adjectives before the noun, when the sentence is respectful or as a way to make it elegant). However, I think « ***illustre majesté*** » is best because the adjective contains 2 syllables, versus 3 for the noun, allowing it not to be overshadowed. But perhaps I’m missing a semantical difference that leaves « altesse » as being a better word choice.

<s>Also, « *Son* » and « *Votre* » can be used interchangeably (unsure which is most respectful though).</s>

Comment: *Son* and *votre* are not interchangeable! You introduce with *son* ( or *leurs*) but you address with *votre*.

Comment: ***Son altesse sérénissime*** (À Monaco et ailleurs https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_Altesse_S%C3%A9r%C3%A9nissime )

Comment: @MatTheLemur +1. From my (very!) limited expertise with the French language, your answer seems spot on from a linguistic point of view. From a historical point of view however, you're a bit off; the style of *majesty* (in any European language) was only ever used by kings, queens and those with even grander titles.

Comment: @Personne The page that you linked to includes the phrase ***Altesse illustrissime***, so that's what I'll go with for the time being.

Comment: @chancellorofpaphos Ok, I figured there might be a difference in the rank it's used to designate. Good to know, as well as for the "Votre" and "Son" (which should be obvious to a French guy, but somehow went over my head I guess)

Comment: @chancellorofpaphos  … pas trouvé le mot *illustrissime* dans cette page … que cela ne vous empêche pas de faire comme bon vous semble :-) — P.S. Mon commentaire est mal écrit, la véritable graphie contient des majuscules **Son Altesse Sérénissime**

Comment: @Personne Right at the bottom of the page, if you click on the "afficer" next to where it says "Prédicats honorifiques", there's a list of exotic forms of address, including "Altesse impériale et royale", "Altesse grand-ducale" and, indeed, "Altesse illustrissime".

Comment: @chancellorofpaphos … En effet, mais ce titre est réservé à la Russie dont la noblesse parlait maîtrisait le français à l'époque. Pour la noblesse de ce côté de l'Oural *Sérénissime* est utilisé. L'élégance de votre traduction sera de tenir compte de cette géographie honorifique.